# Lock a file even when application(C#/WPF) is closed

Tags: c#, wpf, file

i want to store some global application settings on a server. The global settings can only be set from a password restricted area in the application.

If this happens, the file will be stored at the defined server path and when the application is restarted it tries to access the path and load the file. If the path it not accessible it will use the settings from the last run and indicate that a connection wasn't possible.

**Now what i still need** is a lock for the file or something that prevents a user to change the file and save it. Because without a lock a user could just manipulate the csv file, which will then be loaded at next restart.

I already tried to set the Fileaccess with a file stream, but it looks like the access flags are only valid while the filestram is open.

Somebody has an idea how to lock a file even after the application is closed? Or at least set the external access only to read not to read/write?

Comment: _"something that prevents a user to change the file"_ - digital signature?

Comment: The operating system let's you set a file's access rights by user or user group. Whatever program it is that is the only one that can write the file should be run by the only user who has permission to write. Isn't that sufficient control?

Comment: Sorry, but you're doing it wrong.

If you would like to prevent user to modify settings out of the application, then do NOT store app settings in flat file (csv file).

Use binary file instead. 

I'd suggest to create class which will holds all settings.

Comment: You need to set correct permissions, and have a service account that is the only one that can access it. But if the user is local administrator (`su` in linux), then they can do anything, including reading and writing your memory while your app is running

Answer (score 0):

As all others already mentioned, either use file access rights and if this is not possible (cause an admin can always access the file) use some kind of encryption. Either the whole file to make it unreadable or calculate some hash out of the content (with some private salt added) and add this hash to the file.

When you then read the file on next restart you recalculate the hash again and compare it to the stored one. If it matches, the file wasn't altered.

But be aware that then still replay attacks are possible. A user could save an older version of a valid state file locally and later bring it back to you.

And just to answer your initial question:

No it is not possible to lock a file, that it is only accessible for your process. Especially, when it is located on a network folder. In that case the server decides who can access that file.